# Not able to see the Button "Sign in with GitHub" in JupyterHub login page even after Configuring with GitHub OAuthenticator

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, jupyterhub, django-oauth, github-oauth

We should see the **GitHub** login button in **JupyterHub** Login page [GitHub Login button in JupyterHub Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2eOK.png)
But getting the JupyterHub Login page instead of GitHub Login Button Even After Configuring with GitHub OAuth [JupyterHub login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Zkv.png)

**Description:**
I want to integrate custom Authenticator for JupyterHub Application instead of Default authentication provided by default Login Page.
I have a Django Application with OAuth functionality Where it is having client_id and client_Secretkey and I want to Integrate OAuth with JupyterHub Application.

**Steps to Replicate:**

**1.** I Registered the Application in Github and Provided the Application(JupyterHub) Home page URL and Authorization callback URL.

**2.** I followed this Document to configure the **GitHub OAuth** in JupyterHub
**https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/howto/auth/github.html**

**Note:**

I am running **jupyterhub/jupyterhub** image in docker container

**3.** I logged into container and generated the config file in **/etc/jupyterhub**(file location)

**4.** **jupyterhub --generate-config -f jupyterhub_config.py**

**5.** Added the Following lines in **jupyterhub_config.py**

from oauthenticator.github import GitHubOAuthenticator
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = GitHubOAuthenticator
c.GitHubOAuthenticator.oauth_callback_url = **'http://<jupyterhub_url/hub/oauth_callback'**
c.GitHubOAuthenticator.client_id = '**client_id**'(Replaced with GitHub client_id)
c.GitHubOAuthenticator.client_secret = '**client_secretkey**'(Replaced with GitHub client_secret_key)
c.GitHubOAuthenticator.login_service = 'GitHub'

**Restarted** the Container Once after Everything is Configured

We should see the **GitHub login button in JupyterHub Login page**
But getting the same **JupyterHub Login page instead of GitHub Login Button.**